# JavaScript performance for iterating and accessing items

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have an array of items which I sometimes need to iterate and sometimes access a member directly. So I decided to keep references in two variables, one array and one object. I do something like this:

```
const itemsArr = [];
const itemsObj = {};
const addItem = (data) => {
    const item = {
        id: data.id,
        name: data.name
    };
    itemsArr.push(item);
    itemsObj[data.id] = item;
}

const removeItem = (data) => {
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; i++) {
        if (itemsArr[i].id === data.id) {
            itemsArr.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    itemsObj[data.id] = null;
    delete itemsObj[data.id];
}

const getWithId = (id) => {
    return itemsObj[id];
}

const getWithName = (name) => {
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; i++) {
        if (itemsArr[i].name === name) {
            return itemsArr[i];
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

So I manage two objects and use one or another depending on the task, I feel like this is the most performant way but maybe there are better ways for this, like a Map or Set.

Is there a single JavaScript data structure that will outperform arrays in iteration and objects in lookup?

I think `Object.keys` have additional performance costs for iterating an object, similarly `Array.filter` for lookup on an array, so my intuition is to use arrays for iteration and objects for lookup, but if there is a single data structure that is optimized for both, I would like to know and use only one `items` in my code.

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, you never access by *index*, right? Just `id` or `name`?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by index. Like position in array? If so, no. I use object keys as same as the item id's and acces with that. In reality, items have more keys, like `dateCreated` etc but I just wrote two for simplicity.

Comment: Yes, the position of an element in array is called its index.

Comment: Yeah no, the ordering is not relevant for me. I just use an array since I think its the fastest thing to iterate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for the lookup-by-id part of things, I'd suggest a `Map`, not an object. Objects are optimized for the common programming use case where their set of properties is fairly consistent over time (the values may change, but the *shape* of the object [what properties it has] mostly doesn't). `Map` is optimized as a general name/value store that handles that use case better. More in [on this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps).

> Is there a single Javascript data structure that will outperform arrays in iteration and objects in lookup?

No, but the difference in iteration speed between a `Map` and an array won't matter in the **vast** majority of applications. Yes, an array will be faster in most cases (it depends a bit on how the array is built), but it's just really unlikely to matter.

But if you only ever access by `id` or `name`, you aren't iterating anyway. You might want two maps rather than a map and an array, since that way finding items either way is sublinear rather than linear. It also makes for simpler code:

```
const itemsByName = new Map();
const itemsById = new Map();
const addItem = (data) => {
    const item = {
        id: data.id,
        name: data.name
    };
    itemsByName.set(data.name, data);
    itemsByid.set(data.id, data);
};

const removeItem = (data) => {
    itemsByName.delete(data.name);
    itemsByid.delete(data.id);
};

const getWithId = (id) => {
    return itemsById.get(id);
};

const getWithName = (name) => {
    return itemsByName.get(name);
};
```

FWIW, if you didn't have `itemsByName` in the above because you didn't need `name` lookup to be sublinear, here's what the code for `getWithName` would look like using `itemsById`:

```
const getWithName = (name) => {
    for (const item of itemsById.values()) {
        if (data.name === name) {
            return data;
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```

Comment: That's a very good idea actually. But if I do lookups by other keys, I will need more Maps I guess. But I still like the idea! I can do a mixture and use Maps for most common lookups and an array for less frequent ones maybe.

Comment: @wololoo - I'd just use a `Map` and iterate it for the less-common lookups. As I said above, the speed of iteration between a `Map` and an array just won't matter for the vast majority of cases. Worry about it if/when it's a problem. I've added an example of what `getWithName` would look like if you didn't have `itemsByName` and only had `itemsById`.

Comment: Could you please explain why a Map instead of an Object? I could do the same thing with an Object too, right? (Given that the `name`s are unique, which we can safely assume). In my understanding, `Map` is also an `Object` so using a plain Object feels better? For this reason I never used Maps before :p

Comment: @wololoo - See [this secton of the MDN `Map` documenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps). Yes, `Map`s are objects but `get` and `set` aren't doing property operations, so it's not just some added layer on top (in fact, it's more likely a layer of complexity removed).

Comment: Yup.. the documentation says `Performs better in scenarios involving frequent additions and removals of key-value pairs.` which is all I wanted to hear :p Ability to get the number of items and not needing to check `hasOwnProperty` are good bonuses as well. I think I will try Maps. Thank you so much for your help!